# How do I resize a user uploaded image that overflows the container?

Tags: html

I have a container that a user can enter their own text and images in. When I view it on mobile, the text resizes, but if there is an image, it overflows the container. I know I can use the overflow properties to scroll through or crop the image, but is there a way to resize the image for mobile screens instead?

The code I have is below:

```
    <div class="container">
           {{ editable_field("page-body-text", "Page Body Text", "text", "froala", "Insert text or image") }}
    </div>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Use `max-width: 100%` in CSS.

Comment: I didn't see this comment @SLaks ! :)

Answer (score 1):

Use like this:

```
<div class="container">
     <img class="image" ... />
</div>

.image{
    max-width : 100%
}
```

Comment: The issue is that I don't have a set space for an image, just a container that takes any type of media. How do I refer to the image a user might place in this container?

Comment: "User might place in the container", means the left and top of the image  might be in different place?

Comment: Yes, there may or may not be an image, and if there is, I'm not sure how to reference it in <img class="image".../>.

Comment: very simple: if your selector be `.image` it lockups every elements (such as `div`, `span`, ...)  which has the `image` class.